# https with SID not working

Tags: multistore, session, https

I made multiple stores in the sub directories(language is store name).
And all the stores use https.
But the problem is that when i switch to another store, it become logged out automatically.
In normal case, SID should work properly across stores, but it is not working.

SID arguments looks normal.
ex)

https://www.domain.com/english/?SID=4ij4mjs9f71ct7m6rvod0vbjb0&___store=encode

But if i use http, not https, every thing works like magic, So SID works only for http, not https.

```
The setting that i use is these.

"Use SID on Frontend" - YES

"Use Secure URLs in Frontend" - YES

secure "Base URL" - https://www.domain.com

secure "Base Link URL" - {{unsecure_base_url}}english/

unsecure "Base URL" - https://www.domain.com

unsecure "Base Link URL" - {{secure_base_url}}english/

"Cookie Lifetime" - 86400

"Cookie Path" - 

"Cookie Domain" - 

"Use HTTP Only" - YES

"Cookie Restriction Mode" - YES
```

SSL certificate domain is "www.domain.com", "domain.com"

Answer (score -2):

I have changed my "Cookie Path" from empty to  "/".
It solve this issue.

I guess SID or frontend_cid is not working well in the cross stores of https with subdirectory environment.

Something like subdirectory causes session cookie path confused in the https.